vform not sending bearer token
I'm using a custom axios plugin in my Vue 3 Laravel 11 project.  In that plugin I have:
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
});

// Request interceptor to add the token
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    (request) => {

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        if (token) {  console.log(token)
            request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

        }
        return request;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

export default axiosInstance;

This works for all of my requests except when I use vform.  In this case I can see that there's no Bearer token in my network tab.  According to the docs, I should be able to just do Form.axios = axiosInstance. With:
this.assignmentForm.axios = axiosInstance
const {data} = await this.assignmentForm.patch(`/api/assignments/${this.assignment.id}`) 

no token is being sent (though it does appear in the console log so a token does exist).  With a regular posting of the form (i.e. just using my axios plugin), I can submit the form.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. It's not shown what assignmentForm is, it looks like it's an instance of vform. The docs show Form.axios = (static class property), not form.axios = (class instance property). This is probably the problem here

This was the issue!  What I should have used was:    Form.axios = axiosInstance; this.assignmentForm  = new Form(this.assignment).
